# My website does not display images after upload

Tags: html, image

I set up a test server and uploaded a website to it. However, my images don't display at all. I've tried this link which is correct: andra.netimagio.ro/wixwebsite/images/logo.png and the image does not display. For the same reason, the website does not display at all since it is image based.
I've also tried to upload an image alone and it still does not display.

Thank you!

Comment: check the permissions of the uploaded content.

Comment: It would help to know what software/protocol you are using to upload the images and details about the server such as OS and web server software.

Comment: The files were uploaded through Filezilla and I changed permission to 755. I don't know the OS as it's not my server but I think it's Windows

Comment: Just noticed web server software is nginx/1.6.1, images respond with 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using FTP to upload the images, you may be uploading them in ASCII mode, but images need to be uploaded in binary mode. This would explain why your text/html files appear to work, but not your images.

It could also be a permissions issue as another user has commented, to be sure set the permissions on the images folder and contained files to 777 and see if it works.

Also you may want to check that there is no .htaccess file in the root directory or if there is, check that the file does not contain instructions to modify URL requests for the images folder or parent folders.

Hope this helps.